# How does one properly escape a leading "#" character in linux etc/environment?

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services

I would like to store a system-wide environment variable in `etc/environment` on AWS Linux AMI  2013.03. In this example, I am trying to store the phrase "#hello". See the examples below. `echo $control` produces

`hello`

I expected `echo $test0` (below) to produce:

`#hello`

but instead it produces a blank line. The following is list of tests I typed into `/etc/environment`:

- `control="hello"`
- `test0="#hello"`
- `test1="h\\#ello"`
- `test2="h\#ello"`
- `test3="h//#ello"`
- `test4="h/#ello"`
- `test5=h#ello`
- `test6=h\\#ello`
- `test7=h\#ello`
- `test8=h//#ello`
- `test9=h/#ello`
- `test10='h#ello'`
- `test11='h\\#ello'`
- `test12='h\#ello'`
- `test13='h//#ello'`
- `test14='h/#ello'`

If I log out then log back into the machine, it will correctly parse /etc/environment. The control condition passes on `echo $control`. However, none of the test cases correctly respond. In each instance, the string beyond the hash (#) is either chomped or ignored. For example, `echo $test5` produces `h`. Is there a better way to properly escape the `#`?

Interestingly, if I execute `source /etc/environment` then all works as expected and indeed both `echo $control` and `echo $test` produce the intended result. But, upon logout/login, the problem returns...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well it is tricky stuff you want to do /etc/environment is not shell syntax, it looks like one , but it is not, which does frustrates people.
The idea behind /etc/environment was wonderful.  A shell-independent way to set up variables!  Yay!  But the practical limitations make it useless.

You can't pass variables in there.
Try for example put MAIL=$HOME/Maildir/ into it and see what happens.
Best just to stop trying to use it for any purpose whatsoever, alas.
So you can't do things with it that you would expect to be able to do if it were processed by a shell.

Use /etc/profile or /etc/bashrc.

Comment: yeah; before i even posted this I resorted to an actual bash script in /etc/profile.d -- but as you mentioned, i found it immensely frustrating and thought there must be a better way

Comment: Good Luck finding one, but i do not think there is one. As /etc/environment was meant for simple declaration of global variables, If you do not want to use shell specific approach you could try to use /etc/security/pam_env.conf, I remember there you could escape @ and $, and path expansion worked, not sure about # character.